# Deleteing object from $_SESSION array

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I've got a problem with removing object from **'$_SESSION'** array.
My aim is to delete each product from array after choosing one particular. This is the view part:

```
<?php                   
  for ($i=0; $i < count($this->products); $i++) { 
     echo "<a class='remove_from_basket' href='" .$this->baseUrl. "/shop/delete-product/id/" .$this->products[$i]->product_id. "'>Delete</a>";
  }    
?>
```

Then in PHP part I get this products ID with:

```
public function deleteProductAction() {    
        $productID = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
        session_start();
        $obj = $_SESSION['products'];    
        foreach ($obj as $key => $product) {
            if ($product['product_id'] == $productID) {
                unset($product);
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['products'] = $obj;    
    }
```

$obj after printing_r:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Zend_Db_Table_Row Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 26
                )

            [_cleanData:protected] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 26

            [_modifiedFields:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_table:protected] => 
            [_connected:protected] => 
            [_readOnly:protected] => 
            [_tableClass:protected] => Application_Model_DbTable_Products
            [_primary:protected] => Array
                (
                    [1] => product_id
                )

        )

    [3] => Zend_Db_Table_Row Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 26
                )

            [_cleanData:protected] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 26
                )

            [_modifiedFields:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_table:protected] => 
            [_connected:protected] => 
            [_readOnly:protected] => 
            [_tableClass:protected] => Application_Model_DbTable_Products
            [_primary:protected] => Array
                (
                    [1] => product_id
                )

        )

)
```

However, nothing happens... Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Here, in your code, you are just unsetting the `$product`, which is totally not related to your session variable. You need to use the `index` of the object and unset it in the original object.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $key => $product) {
    if ($product['product_id'] == $productID) {
        unset($_SESSION['products'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Or just for the `$obj` you want to do, you can do like:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $product) {
    if ($product['product_id'] == $productID) {
        unset($obj[$key]);
    }
}
```

The above code removes the index completely.

Comment: Ok, but ofter using this, when displaying in view part I get a notice in this particular index: Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: @Peter There's no way you can get that. Which block of code generated it?

Comment: The first for loop.

Comment: @Peter That shouldn't happen... But anyway, try the second one as you wanna make the changes to the `$obj` and lemme know if it works?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's the same problem: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object and Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: @Peter I want to reproduce the same thing in my system so that I can solve it. Can you do a `var_export($obj)` and update your question please? Ha! Non-Object. Wow...

Comment: I would add a check in the of statement to see if the data you want to unset is present. Like this:  `if (isset($_SESSION['products'][$key]) && $product['product_id'] == $productID) {
        unset($_SESSION['products'][$key]);`
    }`

Comment: @Sitethief doesn't `unset` quietly unsets?

Comment: You are correct there _This is probably trivial but there is no error for unsetting a non-existing variable._

Comment: I would guess that the `$this->_getParam('id', 0);`   part tries to get something with index 0 and that fails. Showing us the entire Notice would be beneficial. Or there is no entry on the 0 index in $this->products[$i]->product_id where $i = 0

Comment: @Peter `var_export` not `var_dump` or `print_r`. But this could help as well.

Comment: Actually, before going to delete function there is an entry. And $this->_getParam('id', 0); gets the correct parameter.

Comment: @Peter Ah nice... Hey, is it possible to use some kind of ... Er... Let's say... Cloud9 or something to solve this? Looks complex! `:(`